# Calculate month different using radMonthYearPicker

Tags: asp.net, telerik, asp.net-ajax, 3-tier

I have 2 radMonthYearPicker(1 is for start Date another 1 is for end Date)
I want to calculate the month different between this 2 date.

for my start Date, I set my month as dec and year 2012.
for my end Date, I set my month as dec and year 2013

Base on this 2 RadMonthYearPicker, the month apart should be 12 month

The only code I can find out is RadMonthYearPicker.selectedDate

P.S. I was not allow to upload image file due to lack of repulation point

Comment: the Month difference? Would that be the number of months between 2 dates? Show us an exameple (startdate, enddate and desired result).

Comment: I just updated the content

Answer (score 0):

```
int monthsApart = 12 * (startDate.Year - endDate.Year) + 
   startDate.Month - endDate.Month;

int result = Math.Abs(monthsApart);
```

Comment: To clarify Win's answer: `startDate` should be used as `RadMonthYearPicker1.SelectedDate` where `RadMonthYearPicker1` should be replaced by the name you gave to your "start date" control. Same should be done with the control used for "end date".