# calculate month different using radMonthYearPicker(telerik)

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, asp.net-ajax, 3-tier

> Exact Duplicate of [Calculate month different using
>   radMonthYearPicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13767864/calculate-month-different-using-radmonthyearpicker)

I have 2 radMonthYearPicker(1 is for start Date another 1 is for end Date) I want to calculate the month different between this 2 date.

for my start Date, I set my month as dec and year 2012. for my end Date, I set my month as dec and year 2013

Base on this 2 RadMonthYearPicker, the month apart should be 12 month

The only code I can find out is RadMonthYearPicker.selectedDate

P.S. I was not allow to upload image file due to lack of repulation point

Comment: Maybe this post will help, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525990/difference-in-months

Comment: That doesn't help but thanks anyway

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculate month different using radMonthYearPicker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13767864/calculate-month-different-using-radmonthyearpicker)

Answer (score 0):

```
            int monthApart = 12 * (RMYP_startDate.SelectedDate.Value.Year - RMYP_endDate.SelectedDate.Value.Year) +
        RMYP_startDate.SelectedDate.Value.Month - RMYP_endDate.SelectedDate.Value.Month;
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe this will work for you

```
var monthDifference = ((startDate.selectedDate.Year - endDate.selectedDate.Year) * 12) + startDate.selectedDate.Month - endDate.selectedDate.Month
```

[Difference in months between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638993/difference-in-months-between-two-dates)